# Select DISTINCT rows from multiple tables where only 1 column has the distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get distinct rows when I run the following query. But I get rows that are repeated 
When I use SELECT DISTINCT I get an error, and GROUP BY is the same I know it is possible but I having trouble figuring it out

The distinct records are in the first column TEST.TEST_ID

```
SELECT TEST.TEST_ID, TEST.TEST_TYP_ID, TEST.LOCATIONSECTIONID, TY.NAME, TEST.TITLE, TXT.TEXT, TEST.REPORT_DATE, TEST.START_DATE, TEST.END_DATE, SC.DISPLAY_NAME, EL.EL_ID, SC.SC_ID, O.DISPLAY_NAME
FROM TEST_TEST AS TEST
    LEFT JOIN TEST_TYPE TY ON TEST.TEST_TYP_ID = TY.TEST_TYP_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_OPTN_TEST OPT ON TEST.TEST_ID = OPT.TEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_OPTN O ON OPT.OPTION_NUMBER = O.OPTION_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN TEST_EL EL ON OPT.EL_ID = EL.EL_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_TXT TXT ON TEST.TEST_ID = TXT.TEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_EL_SC SC ON OPT.EL_ID = SC.EL_ID
WHERE
TEST.TEST_TYP_ID = 1 
AND TEST.TITLE LIKE '%SOME TEXT%'
AND SC.DISPLAY_NAME = 'SOME TEXT'
```

THANKS

Comment: It sounds like DISTINCT might be the way to go, can you tell us what error you're getting?

Comment: So when a test has two test types or two questions which one do you want? Please show some sample data and desired results. You can't just show us 7 left joins and tell us to fix the query.

Comment: Thank you for your help If you think there is a better way to do these JOINS please share.

Answer (score 0):

I got it I was receiving the error 
The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable. (Line 1)
So I removed that column which is TXT.TEXT and I got the distinct rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT TEST.TEST_ID, TEST.TEST_TYP_ID, TEST.LOCATIONSECTIONID, TY.NAME, TEST.TITLE, TEST.REPORT_DATE, TEST.START_DATE, TEST.END_DATE, SC.DISPLAY_NAME, EL.EL_ID, SC.SC_ID, O.DISPLAY_NAME
FROM TEST_TEST AS TEST
    LEFT JOIN TEST_TYPE TY ON TEST.TEST_TYP_ID = TY.TEST_TYP_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_OPTN_TEST OPT ON TEST.TEST_ID = OPT.TEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_OPTN O ON OPT.OPTION_NUMBER = O.OPTION_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN TEST_EL EL ON OPT.EL_ID = EL.EL_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_TXT TXT ON TEST.TEST_ID = TXT.TEST_ID
    LEFT JOIN TEST_EL_SC SC ON OPT.EL_ID = SC.EL_ID
WHERE
TEST.TEST_TYP_ID = 1 
AND TEST.TITLE LIKE '%SOME TEXT%'
AND SC.DISPLAY_NAME = 'SOME TEXT'
```

This worked but would I would do if I want to include that text column.

Thanks

Comment: `ntext` type is deprecated. Use `nvarchar(max)` instead.